# IE11: Content Editable Image resize

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a content editable div which has an image. If the image size is bigger than the div or if I scroll through the contents on the div with the image selected, the image resize icons appear outside the div, as if those icons alone have an higher z-index.

[image]

Code:

```
<iframe src="test.html">
   <div contenteditable="true" >
     <p><img src="0.jpg"/></p>
   </div
</iframe>
```

This seems to be working fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The reported issue in IE11 is a browser behavior and part of the UX of the browser.
The image handle icons are windowed objects part of the browser implementation and unfortunately you cannot control them with JavaScript or CSS to alter their position and location.